Seeking Assistance for Image Path Optimization Algorithm
I'm currently tackling a challenge involving image path optimization and could use some assistance refining my algorithm.
Picture an image represented as an array of integers, with each pixel holding an "energy level" value. The top-left pixel of the image is indexed at (0,0).
My goal is to compute the shortest path, measured by energy, from the top to the bottom of the image. The path may start at any x-coordinate.
Rather than resorting to brute force, I'm exploring a more algorithmic approach. I envision the path progressing downward (incrementing the y-coordinate), with options to move left, straight, or right-down at each step.
Here's the outline of my algorithm:

Start at the top-left corner (0,0).

Determine the next best step by considering a lookahead distance denoted by lookForward.

Return -1, 0, or 1 for left, straight, or right directions.

Progressively find the optimal path by iteratively moving down the image.


I've already implemented most of the algorithm, but I'm currently stuck on refining the lookForward component. I'm seeking help with the PathFinder.getBestStep(x, y, lookForward); method. I know that recursion with methods is necessary to go through each step and find the best path, but despite my efforts, I haven't been able to get it to work.
Here's a snippet of my current code:
for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
    int xOffset = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
        final int bestStep = PathFinder.getBestStep(x + xOffset, y, 5); // "lookForward" distance is set to 5.

        if (bestStep == -1) {
            // Move one step left and one step down
            xOffset -= 1;
        }
        if (bestStep == 0) {
            // Move one step down
        }
        if (bestStep == 1) {
            // Move one step right and one step down
            xOffset += 1;
        }
    }
}

I kinda have this PathFinder class so far:
public class PathFinder {

    public final int[] energyMap; // energyMap is the image.
    public final int width; // Width of image (energyMap).
    public final int height; // Height of image (energyMap).
    public final int lookForward; // Amount of steps, it will lookForward.

    public PathFinder(int[] energyMap, int width, int height, int lookForward) {
        this.energyMap = energyMap;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.lookForward = lookForward;
    }

    // Return the -1, 0 or 1, for left, middle or right, step movement.
    public int getBestStep(final int x, final int y) {
        final List<Integer> bestPath = getBestPath(x + y * width, new ArrayList<>());
        return bestPath.getFirst();
    }

    // Get the shortest path, (based on shortest energy level)
    public List<Integer> getBestPath(final int index, List<Integer> currentPath) {
        // Don't really know what to do here.
        return null;
    }
}

An visualization of what I want:
Let's consider an image that is 10x10, where each pixel represents either 1 or 0 for simplicity:
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1

We can observe a clear path down the image where the "energy" is low. My objective is to identify and follow that path. However, the images I'll be dealing with could be as large as 4000x4000, if not larger. Attempting to brute force the absolute best path would consume a significant amount of time. Hence, I aim to implement a method that only calculates a few steps ahead.
While processing a single 4000x4000 image wouldn't be time-consuming, I might need to repeat this process multiple times, possibly up to 1000 times. It's important to note that absolute precision is unnecessary; I'm primarily interested in identifying roughly the best path. I can adjust the lookForward variable to enhance the quality of the path determination.

Can anyone please explain why I keep getting dislikes? I feel like I've done my own research, formulated my question properly, and I'm not just sitting here wanting people to spoon-feed me code.

learn about graph algorithms. here you need nothing complex. you just run down your matrix, update the least cost for every cell as you go. keep track of the cell you came from, so you can recover the least cost path. -- [tour], [ask]. greetings and salutations are supposed to be omitted. a [mre] is also expected, or at least some data (which you did). -- personally, I'd recommend a more popular language for prototyping: Python. your task does not require speed. if it did, Python is still a good choice (Python can be JIT-compiled in at least one way).

" represented as a 1D array of integers" "The top-left pixel of the image is indexed at (0,0)."  So which is it, 1D or 2D?

Google Dijkstra algorithm.  For some C++ code that does this kind of thing, take a look at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Hills

The simplest approach will be to use a decent graph-theory library.  Most will have implemented Dijsktra in C++, so you can expect decent performance.

@Bredosen, if I may: your original post is very wordy, and you provide more information than people need. Provide just enough information for people to answer your question. If someone wants to know why you're working on this problem, they'll ask. Questions shouldn't be chatty. Thanks for posting the code and the visualization!

eh, more info is better than less info, especially since most questions err towards the vague side. the context is appreciated.

@Rethunk  Please learn to speed read.  If it seems interesting, if it might be something you can contribute to, go back and read for context.  If not, then move along to another question.  Most questions seem to be posted by people who think we can read their minds!

well I agree that a bit more structure wouldn't hurt this question's readability.

Here is some C++ code that solves this problem using the Dijkstra implementation in https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "GraphTheory.h"
#include "cGrid2D.h"

static std::vector<std::string>
tokenize(
    const std::string &line)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    std::stringstream sst(line);
    std::string a;
    while (getline(sst, a, ' '))
        ret.push_back(a);
    return ret;
}

void findpath(std::istream &ifs)
{
    // A directed graph
    raven::graph::sGraphData graphData;
    graphData.g.clear();
    graphData.g.directed();

    // A 2D grid
    cGrid2D grid;
    std::vector<double> vHeight;

    std::string line;
    int colcount = -1;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol;

    // setup grid
    while (getline(ifs, line))
    {
        auto vt = tokenize(line);

        for (auto &e : vt)
        {
            vHeight.push_back(atof(e.c_str()));
        }
        if (colcount == -1)
            colcount = vt.size();
        else if (colcount != vt.size())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "variable column count");
        rowCount++;
    }
    grid.setDim(colcount, rowCount);

    // Path can move only downwards
    grid.addDownEdges();

    // convert grid to graph with weighted edges
    graphData.edgeWeight.clear();
    for (auto &p : grid.getEdgesVertexIndex())
    {
        // add edges to graph with weight of the destination vertex
        graphData.g.add(p.first, p.second);
        graphData.edgeWeight.push_back(vHeight[p.second]);
    }
    // start from any vertex in top row
    int startIndex = graphData.g.vertexCount();
    for (int iv = 0; iv < colcount; iv++)
    {
        graphData.g.add(startIndex, iv);
        graphData.edgeWeight.push_back(vHeight[iv]);
    }
    // end from any vertex in bottom row
    int endIndex = graphData.g.vertexCount();
    for (int iv = endIndex - 1 - colcount; iv < endIndex - 1; iv++)
    {
        graphData.g.add(iv, endIndex);
        graphData.edgeWeight.push_back(0);
    }

    // Apply Dijsktra
    graphData.startName = graphData.g.userName(startIndex);
    graphData.endName = graphData.g.userName(endIndex);
    auto res = raven::graph::path(graphData);

    // Display path found ( col, row )
    int r, c;
    for (int i = 1; i < res.first.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        grid.coords(c, r, res.first[i]);
        std::cout << c << "," << r << " -> ";
    }
    std::cout << " total energy " << res.second << "\n";
}


main()
{
    std::string sin =
        "1 2 3\n"
        "2 3 1\n"
        "3 2 1\n";
    std::istringstream ifs(sin);
    findpath(ifs);

    return 0;
}

which outputs
1,0 -> 2,1 -> 2,2 ->  total energy 4

With this input ( your example )
    std::string sin =
        "1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1\n"
        "1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1\n";

The output is
3,0 -> 4,1 -> 4,2 -> 5,3 -> 5,4 -> 4,5 -> 3,6 -> 4,7 -> 4,8 -> 5,9 ->  total energy 0

AFAIK, Java is just a peculiar version of C++, so you should be able to port this code easily.
